# Using hotkey in specific application, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: autohotkey

**This works:**

wheeldown::
WinGetTitle, Title, A
WinGetClass, Class, A
if (RegExMatch(Title, "Poker"))
       {coordmode, mouse, window
       MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
       mouseclick, left, 325, 341
       MouseMove, StartX, StartY
       }
else
       send {wheeldown}
return

**This doesn't work**

a::
WinGetTitle, Title, A
WinGetClass, Class, A
if (RegExMatch(Title, "Poker"))
       {coordmode, mouse, window
       MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
       mouseclick, left, 510, 342
       send {Backspace}
       send {Backspace}
       send {Backspace}
       send {Backspace}
       send {Backspace}
       send, 1.25
       MouseMove, StartX, StartY
       }
else
       send {a}
return

**Why it not work :(**

Error message comes when I try to use "a" in a different application.  Says 71 hotkeys used in 1000ms or something.

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the top of your script:

```
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 300      ;default is 70
```

The error you get is common to scripts where the mousewheel is captured and used alot.  Autohotkey treats the mousewheel as a hotkey and thinks that you shouldn't push a hotkey more than 70 times per second.  Scrolling can call the hotkey more times then that depending on usage.  This line will allow more than 70.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When I do that, however, say I want to type in "A" into a different window (a window I don't want to use a hotkey for).  It won't type "A", it will just pause for a second, and then not type the letter.

Comment: Try using `inputbox` for the window into which you want to type.

Answer (score 0):

three things, strictly speaking when using a hot key that has multiple lines  of code the first line doesn't immediately follow the double colons. So this:

```
a:: WinGetTitle, Title, A
WinGetClass, Class, A
```

should be this:

```
a::
WinGetTitle, Title, A
WinGetClass, Class, A
```

Secondly the command that you are trying to find is called an imperative by the name of "#IfWinActive" or "#If" your regex should be used with latter of those to commands. There is a lot to that so you will need to look at those in the docs.

Lastly in the using a hotkey which sends itself you need to prefix it with "$" so that this:

```
a::
```

becomes:

```
$a::
```

Hope that helps with the question for any one looking atthis year old post.